# Max number of bytes available for sysfs read

Tags: c, linux-kernel, sysfs

To handle a `sysfs` read I need to create a `show` function which is added to a `kobj_attribute` structure. The prototype of [the function is defined as](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.63/source/include/linux/kobject.h#L145):

```
ssize_t (*show)(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr,
            char *buf);
```

Obviously I need to write data to the `buf` parameter, but what is the upper limit of the number of bytes which can be written? Is it defined anywhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) (search for "Reading/Writing Attribute Data") the buffer size is one page, or `PAGE_SIZE` bytes.

To avoid the warning below, you can effectively only use `PAGE_SIZE - 1` bytes though:

```c
        if (ret >= (ssize_t)PAGE_SIZE) {
                printk("dev_attr_show: %pS returned bad count\n",
                                dev_attr->show);
        }
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I don't plan on writing more than about 10 bytes, but it's always safe to have a sanity check in place :)